# PHP LDAPS connection to AD

Tags: php, ssl, active-directory, ldap, centos7

Connection to Windows AD over SSL using PHP 7.4

```
$ldaphost = "ldaps://...";
$ldapUsername  = "CN=supervisor,OU=test_Users,DC=test,DC=org";
$ldapPassword = "xxxx";


$ds = ldap_connect($ldaphost,636);
echo $ds;

if (!ldap_start_tls($ds)) {
print "Could not start secure TLS connection";
}else {
// now we need to bind to the ldap server
$bth = ldap_bind($ds, $ldapUsername, $ldapPassword) or die("\r\nCould not connect to LDAP server\r\n");
}
```

Error:
ldap_start_tls(): Unable to start TLS: Can't contact LDAP server

After debugging :ldap_connect returns id process as expected. I tried connecting using GUI tool and connection was successful which mean I eliminated certificate issues. I appreciate any ideas to troubleshoot this issue Thanks

Comment: Programs do not necessarily use the same certificates as GUI. You usually need to provide them manually. But I do not know your particular case. I've never done LDAP connection programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

You should *either* use `ldaps` *or* TLS. By now the prefered way is TLS according to LDAPv3. So you'd connect to an unsecured backend using `ldap://` and then call `ldap_start_tls` as the first command (probably after some `ldap_set_option`-calls) but definitely before calling `ldap_bind`.

The problem in your case might be, that the connection to the LDAP-Server does not work at all from the machine in question. As `ldap_connect` does not actually connect but merely creates a handle that can the be used to do the actual connection, connection errors usually fist surface on the first call that requires an actual connection (in your case `ldap_start_tls`). So check that your server is actually reachable on the given port from the machine in question e.g. by calling `telnet servernameOrIp port` or by using a cli-ldap-tool

Another thing is, that you are using `ldap_connect` wrongly. You should add your port to the ldap-uri like this: `ldaps://example.com:636` as specified [in the docs](https://www.php.net/ldap_connect). If you use an LDAP-URL the port-parameter is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `ldap_start_tls` if you've already specified `ldaps://`. Just proceed with your `ldap_bind`.

You only really need to use `ldap_start_tls` if your DC supports TLS on the normal LDAP port 389. In that case you need to explicitly specify that you want to use TLS because you actually have a choice. You don't have a choice on port 636. There's a comment about that in the [documentation for `ldap_start_tls`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-start-tls.php#51879).

Also see "Example #2 Example of connecting securely to LDAP server" in the [documentation for `ldap_connect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ldap-connect.php).

Comment: `ldap_connect` does **not** connect to the LDAP-Server but returns a handle. The actual connection happens on the first command that requires a connection. So that's either `ldap_start_tls` or * ldap_connect`

Comment: I think you meant "or `ldap_bind`"? But yes, I checked the docs and you're correct: `ldap_connect` doesn't actually connect. But ultimately, the solution should be the same: just delete the `ldap_start_tls` line. I've updated my answer.